# Peewee: Relation does not exist when querying with CTE

Tags: python, postgresql, peewee

I want to query the count of bookings for a given event- if the event has bookings, I want to pull the name of the "first" person to book it.

The table looks something like: Event 1-0 or Many Booking, Booking.attendee is a 1:1 with User Table. In pure SQL I can easily do what I want by using Window Functions + CTE. Something like:

```sql
WITH booking AS (
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b.event_id ORDER BY b.created DESC) rn,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY b.event_id) count
  FROM
    booking b JOIN "user" u on u.id = b.attendee_id
  WHERE
    b.status != 'cancelled'
)

SELECT e.*, a.vcount, a.first_name, a.last_name FROM event e LEFT JOIN attendee a ON a.event_id = e.id WHERE (e.seats > COALESCE(a.count, 0) and (a.rn = 1 or a.rn is null) and e.cancelled != true;
```

This gets everything I want. When I try to turn this into a CTE and use Peewee however, I get errors about: Relation does not exist.

***Not exact code***, but I'm doing something like this with some dynamic where clauses for filtering based on params.

```py
cte = (
    BookingModel.select(
        BookingModel,
        peewee.fn.ROW_NUMBER().over(partition_by=[BookingModel.event_id], order_by=[BookingModel.created.desc()]).alias("rn),
        peewee.fn.COUNT(BookingModel.id).over(partition_by=[BookingModel.event_id]).alias("count),
        UserModel.first_name,
        UserModel.last_name
    )
    .join(
        UserModel,
        peewee.JOIN.LEFT_OUTER,
        on(UserModel.id == BookingModel.attendee)
    )
    .where(BookingModel.status != "cancelled")
    .cte("test")


query = (
    EventModel.select(
        EventModel,
        UserModel,
        cte.c.event_id,
        cte.c.first_name,
        cte.c.last_name,
        cte.c.rn,
        cte.c.count
    )
    .join(UserModel, on=(EventModel.host == UserModel.id))
    .switch(EventModel)
    .join(cte, peewee.JOIN.LEFT_OUTER, on=(EventModel.id == cte.c.event_id))
    .where(where_clause)
    .order_by(EventModel.start_time.asc(), EventModel.id.asc())
    .limit(10)
    .with_cte(cte)
```

After reading the docs twenty+ times, I can't figure out what isn't right about this. It looks like the samples... but the query will fail, because "relation "test" does not exist". I've played with "columns" being explicitly defined, but then that throws an error that "rn is ambiguous".

I'm stuck and not sure how I can get Peewee CTE to work.

EDIT: Generated query

```sql
WITH "attendee" AS (SELECT "t1"."id", "t1"."event_id", "t1"."attendee_id", "t1"."created", ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "t1"."event_id" ORDER BY "t1"."created" DESC) AS "rn", COUNT("t1"."id") OVER (PARTITION BY "t1"."event_id") AS "count", "t2"."first_name", "t2"."last_name" FROM "booking" AS "t1" LEFT OUTER JOIN "user" AS "t2" ON ("t2"."id" = "t1"."attendee_id") WHERE ("t1"."status" != 'cancelled')) SELECT "t3"."id", "t3"."created", "t3"."updated", "t3"."course_id", "t3"."organizer_id", "t3"."sequence", "t3"."title", "t3"."desc", "t3"."seats", "t3"."location", "t3"."start_time", "t3"."end_time", "t3"."cancelled", "t4"."id", "t4"."created", "t4"."updated", "t4"."organization_id", "t4"."email", "t4"."first_name", "t4"."last_name", "attendee"."event_id", "attendee"."first_name", "attendee"."last_name", "attendee"."rn", "attendee"."count" FROM "event" AS "t3" INNER JOIN "user" AS "t4" ON ("t3"."organizer_id" = "t4"."id") LEFT OUTER JOIN "attendee" ON ("t3"."id" = "attendee"."event_id") WHERE (((("t3"."course_id" = '1d5687cb8d7b4211a461b353ecd4f5ec') AND (("attendee"."rn" = 1) OR ("attendee"."rn" IS NULL))) AND ("t3"."start_time" >= 0)) AND ("t3"."end_time" <= 3000)) ORDER BY "t3"."start_time" ASC, "t3"."id" ASC LIMIT 2
```

Comment: Can you share the SQL generated by the above query? You can get this with `print(query)`.

Comment: Dumped it at the bottom of the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a ctrl+f for the string "test" and found it nowhere in the generated SQL, so something doesn't add up for me. Similarly, "attendee"."rn" seems well-specified, so I can't quite figure out where your issue is. Working backwards from the SQL, I produced the simplified models:

```
class User(db.Model):
    name = TextField()

class Event(db.Model):
    title = TextField()
    organizer = ForeignKeyField(User)

class Booking(db.Model):
    status = TextField()
    event = ForeignKeyField(Event)
    attendee = ForeignKeyField(User)
```

I populated some sample data and wrote the following simplified query:

```
cte = (Booking
       .select(Booking.event,
               User.name,
               fn.ROW_NUMBER().over(
                   partition_by=[Booking.event],
                   order_by=[Booking.id.desc()]).alias('rn'),
               fn.COUNT(Booking.id).over(
                   partition_by=[Booking.event]).alias('count'))
       .join(User, JOIN.LEFT_OUTER)
       .where(Booking.status != 'cancelled')
       .cte('attendee'))

query = (Event
         .select(Event, User.name.alias('organizer_name'),
                 cte.c.name,
                 cte.c.rn,
                 cte.c.count)
         .join(User)
         .join_from(Event, cte, JOIN.LEFT_OUTER, on=(Event.id == cte.c.event_id))
         .where(cte.c.rn == 1)
         .order_by(Event.id)
         .with_cte(cte))
```

Iterating over the query appears correct:

```
for row in query:
    print(
        row.title,  # Event title.
        row.organizer.name,  # Organizer's name.
        row.attendee['name'],  # Attendee name from cte.
        row.attendee['rn'],  # Row number from cte.
        row.attendee['count'])  # Count from cte.
```

Note: the results from the CTE are stored in a dict, as we don't have a well-defined model to use to reconstruct the join graph.

The above query produces the following SQL, which executes without issue:

```
WITH "attendee" AS (
    SELECT "t1"."event_id", "t2"."name", 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "t1"."event_id" ORDER BY "t1"."id" DESC) AS "rn", 
      COUNT("t1"."id") OVER (PARTITION BY "t1"."event_id") AS "count" 
    FROM "booking" AS "t1" 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "user" AS "t2" ON ("t1"."attendee_id" = "t2"."id")
    WHERE ("t1"."status" != ?)) 
SELECT "t3"."id", "t3"."title", "t3"."organizer_id", 
       "t4"."name" AS "organizer_name", 
       "attendee"."name", 
       "attendee"."rn", 
       "attendee"."count" 
FROM "event" AS "t3" 
INNER JOIN "user" AS "t4"
    ON ("t3"."organizer_id" = "t4"."id") 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "attendee"
    ON ("t3"."id" = "attendee"."event_id")
WHERE ("attendee"."rn" = ?)
ORDER BY "t3"."id"
```

Comment: Sorry- it is attendee in my code base not "test". I changed things a little to post here on naming.

Comment: At any rate surely the above should give you the right idea of what the issue is?

Comment: I'm afraid no luck. My generated SQL is the same as above, peewee code looks the same. When attempting to iterate however "Event" has no attribute "attendee". It appears that only the EventModel is returned.

Comment: Oh in that case you may just need to use the proper attribute the cte data was joined onto. Alternatively append ".objects()" onto your query to obtain all attributes on the Event object.

Comment: It's joined on Event.ID, so it looks like it's not being appended onto that attribute as ID remains just a UUID for me (extended base model).

That said, .objects() does the trick.

Slightly unrelated but does Peewee have any way to reuse a CTE thats been defined in "peewee code" for lack of better terms?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if I understand what you mean, but you can always pass around that reference to `cte` and apply it to other queries via `.with_cte(cte)`.